# How to use AWS SDK locally in my Aurelia Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js

I want to use SQS Queue from AWS-SDK locally in my Aurelia project but I am facing problem.

If i use live URL of Amazon AWS-SDK link in Index.ejs then its working fine but if give local script path link then facing errors.

I tried many techniques but failed .In Live Link working fine and no error but in Local path "Config" is undefined error is getting.

Live PATH

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.505.0.min.js"></script>
```

Local Path

```
 <script src="./src/assets/aws-sdk-2.505.0.min.js"></script>
```

on TS file I declare this

```
const AWS = (window as any).AWS;

  AWS.config.credentials = {
      "accessKeyId": "xxxxxxx",
      "secretAccessKey": "xxxxxx",
      "region": "xxxx"
    };
    AWS.config.region = "xxxxxx";
    AWS.config.version = "xxxxx";
    this.queueURL = "xxxxxxx";
 }
```

I can achieve this by NPM install but this is increasing size of project thats why I want to use locally in project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If size of the bundle is the main issue for you, aws-sdk provides the option to include only the services you need.  There is a bit of explanation on this in the [aws-sdk README](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js#in-nodejs-1) where you can do the following with the npm package imported:

```js
// option 1. import entire SDK
// this is big, indeed
import * as aws from 'aws-sdk';

// option 2a. import AWS object without services
// that's pretty basic
import * as aws from 'aws-sdk/global';

// option 2b. import individual service
// this might be just what you need, combined with option 2a.
import * as s3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
```

Important notice: I changed the import a bit than what the README states. Simply because the TS compiles errors out that the aws-sdk module has no default export.

A full sample, based on your original example, that would significantly reduce the size of your output bundle would be:

```js
// only include the 'global' (core) and 's3' service
import * as aws from 'aws-sdk/global';
import * as s3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

export class App {
  public attached() {
    aws.config.credentials = {
      "accessKeyId": "xxxxxxx",
      "secretAccessKey": "xxxxxx"
    };

    aws.config.region = "xxxxxx";
    aws.config.apiVersion = "xxxxx";
  }
}
```

Not to be nitpicky, but some of the options from your sample simply don't work - so these are removed.

Still, if that isn't enough convincing, you *could* try reverting to including the CDN in the `<head>` tag of `index.ejs` and declare it globally using var on top of your class:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

... but I wouldn't go that way and would personally favour a larger bundle over an additional remote http call.